# How to switch application for Windows 10 Media Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, overlay

When Media Key is used in Windows 10, the last used application will be activated. This is annoying when I am using the ebook reader Freda, and I want the media key to be used on Spotify/YouTube that is running in Chrome

[image: Freda Windows Media Key Overlay]

What is the shortcut key to activate the `Next Application` so that the media keys will be used on Chrome instead?

Comment: You can set up an AutoHotKey script which will detect if freda is open and intercept the media keys commands to send them to Chrome instead. See this post https://superuser.com/questions/1212672/keyboard-media-keys-in-windows-is-it-possible-to-override-which-app-responds-t